# Unable to create tables on a grid in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

> I am trying to create x tables on a GridLayout where x is the size of the list, **mylist**.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import *

class basicWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)
        mylist = [['Admin',['int a','int b','int c'],
['Student',['int a','int b','int c','int d','int e']]]


        for i in range(len(mylist)):
                table = QTableWidget()
                table.setColumnCount(1)
                table.setRowCount(len(mylist[i][1]))
                for j in range(len(mylist[i][1])):
                    table.setItem(j,0,QTableWidgetItem(mylist[i][1][j]))
                vBox = QVBoxLayout()
                vBox.addWidget(table)
                grid.addWidget(vBox,i,0)
    
        self.setWindowTitle('Basic Grid Layout')

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     windowExample = basicWindow()
     windowExample.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> But everytime I run this code. It gives me the error below. I have tried adding the maximum number of arguments for addWidget method for both Vbox and Grid,respectively. But it also does not seems to be working. Please guide because I'm stuck on this for a while now.

```
 TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
 addWidget(self, QWidget): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QVBoxLayout'
 addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = 
 Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QVBoxLayout'
 addWidget(self, QWidget, int, int, int, int, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = 
 Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QVBoxLayout'
```

Comment: change `grid.addWidget(vBox,i,0)` to `grid.addLayout(vBox,i,0)`

Comment: @eyllanesc , thanks a lot ! its working. But what difference does addLayout makes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it should be clear from the documentation of [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-1), that function requires that you use a **`QWidget`** subclass as first argument, and QVBoxLayout is **not**.

If you want to add a layout, you need to use [`addLayout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addLayout) instead.

It's not very clear why you need to use a QVBoxLayout (since you're not adding anything else except from the table, which makes that layout completely useless), but, anyway, just change the following line:

```
    grid.addWidget(vBox,i,0)
```

to this:

```
    grid.addLayout(vBox, i, 0)
```

<sub>Please always add a space after very comma, as suggested from the official [Python code style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).</sub>

Comment: Actually this is a portion of my code and I am not trying to add just a single table. Btw, very Helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RabiSiddique You're welcome! If my answer solved your problem, remember to set it as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left of it.